# $\lim _{x \to a}f(x)=\lim _{x \to a}\frac{f(x)\times g(x)}{g(x)}$

Tags: limits

$$1-)\lim _{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x^2 }{x}$$

$$2-)\lim _{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x^2 }{x}\times \frac{x}{x}$$

$$3-)\lim _{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x^2 }{x^2}\times x$$

$$4-)\lim _{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x^2 }{x^2}\times\lim _{x \to 0} x=1\times0=0$$

now : in Step (2) why We can $\frac{\sin x^2 }{x}$in  $\times \frac{x}{x}$?

We know that if be $x=0$ then $1/0=$Undefined

Generally: prove that :

if $$g(a)=0$$

then :

$$\lim _{x \to a}f(x)=\lim _{x \to a}\frac{f(x)\times g(x)}{g(x)}$$

thank you .

Comment: In general if $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exists then you can do what you did.

Comment: @kingW3: this has nothing to do with limit of $g(x) $ as $x\to a$.

Answer (score 1):

A limit is the value a function approaches as $x$ approaches some point.  As long as it is true that

$$f(x)=f(x)\frac{g(x)}{g(x)}$$

for $x$ near the point it is approaching (but not necessarily **at** the point), then we may have

$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\frac{g(x)}{g(x)}$$

Comment: Thus as long $g(x) \neq 0$ as $x\to a$ the desired equation holds.  This is independent of the the fact whether limit of $g(x) $ as $x\to a$ exists or not. +1